# How does this query work in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. This is a query that I do not understand:

```
declare @tempDoc xml

set @tempDoc = '<Root>
<ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Hovercraft">
<Features>
  <Passengers>60 passenger capacity</Passengers>
  <Performance>Top speed: 200 KMPH</Performance>
  <Maintenance>5 year parts and labor extended maintenance </Maintenance>
</Features>
</ProductDescription>
</Root>';

SELECT @tempDoc.query('/Root/ProductDescription/Features/Passengers');
```

The select returns this:

```
 <Passengers>60 passenger capacity</Passengers>
```

Can you please tell me what it does, does it delete the other nodes?

I am not able to understand this.

Comment: Actually your query gives result like this - `<Passengers>60 passenger capacity</Passengers>`

Comment: @SelvaTS : yes,updated.

Comment: What is your question really? You are querying for the Passengers and get the Passengers node. I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It selects the Passengers-node from the xml stored in variable `@tempDoc`.

You have the exact "location" in the query: `Root -> ProductDescription -> Features -> Passengers`.

Pretty straight forward and no, it does not delete the rest. The variable still contains the full `xml`, but you have selected to only retrieve the `passengers-node`.

You can read more about `XQuery language` here for example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx

> To query an XML instance stored in a variable or column of xml type, you use the xml Data Type Methods. For example, you can declare a variable of xml type and query it by using the query() method of the xml data type.

Answer (score 0):

The query method outputs the passenger node(s) from the specified path(s) found in the tempDoc variable.

Check out the msdn documentation for the [xml datatype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) and the [query method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The `query()` method in `XQuery` extracts the value from the `XML` and it does not delete node from original data.

From [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx),

> The **query()** method takes an XQuery expression that evaluates to a
>   list of XML nodes and allows the user to extract fragments of an XML
>   document. The result of this method is an instance of untyped XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, it extract the value which you give in parameter. If you are working xml in c# and want to extract the node value.

The same thing done in SQL Server too. You just use `XQuery` and give the path of your tree means node path to extract value. There is so many thing you will done in xml, read value, read node, read properties or attributes , parsing xml to a table etc.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/manipulating-xml-data-in-sql-server/

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/